# Adding program to startup

Tags: c#

I have created a program which I built to an exe as the release build. When you double click the exe the program should add itself to the startup so everytime the pc is booted, the program runs. It however does not add it to the startup despite getting no errors. The program also runs as expected.

This is the code which handles adding the program to the startup:

```
 public static void AddApplicationToStartup()
 {
     using(RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true))
     {
         key.SetValue("WindowsProcesses", "\"" + Application.ExecutablePath + "\"");
     }

 }
```

...this code is written inside the main 'Program' class.

Comment: Where is your error checking on `key.SetValue`? Does `WindowsProcesses` exist? If so, does your value get added there? (Atually, where is your error checking on `OpenSubKey`?)

Comment: Don't do this. This is bad behavior for a program.

Comment: Here is a good CodePlex article on how to accomplish this from C#. The article seems very straight forward but basically uses Windows DLLs to create the shortcut.   http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146757/Add-Remove-Startup-Folder-Shortcut-to-Your-App

Comment: once again, no errors but I check the startup folder and no shortcut has been created :(

Answer (score 0):

Add application path this way

```
   public static void AddApplicationToStartup()
        {

            using (RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true))
            {
                key.SetValue("WindowsProcesses", Application.ExecutablePath.ToString());
            }

        }
```

Comment: third line is missing a bracket at the end but this code gave me the error cannot convert from 'Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey' to 'string'

Comment: @OliverDungey I have updated my code, hope this time will work and won't throw any exception

Comment: Doesn't give me any errors but also hasn't added the program to the registry? Really confused here as this code should work. The program only runs for 10 seconds if that somehow has something to do with it?

Comment: yes its add the program in registry, I have checked, may be problem in somewhere else

Comment: okay' i'll try running the program on a different machine tomorrow to see if it makes any difference.